# System.Text.Json JsonSerializer.Deserialize throws "Each parameter in the deserialization constructor..." exception

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I have the following classes:

```
public class BaseResponse
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public BaseResponse(bool success, string message)
    {
        Success = success;
        Message = message;
    }
}

public class TextToSpeechResponse : BaseResponse
{
    [JsonPropertyName("audioPreviewSuccess")]
    public bool AudioPreviewSuccess { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("result")]
    public SpeechSynthesisResult? Result { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("errorMessage")]
    public string? ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public TextToSpeechResponse(bool audioPreviewSuccess, SpeechSynthesisResult speechResult, string? errorMessage, string message)
        : base(true, message)
    {
        AudioPreviewSuccess = audioPreviewSuccess;
        Result = speechResult;
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public TextToSpeechResponse()
        : base(false, string.Empty)
    {
        AudioPreviewSuccess = false;
        Result              = null;
        ErrorMessage        = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON using this code:

```
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
            DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
        };

        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TextToSpeechResponse>(authorizedResponseBody, options) ??
               new TextToSpeechResponse {
                   Message = "Something went wrong with deserializing the authorizedResponseBody.",
               };
```

The problem is that I get the following exception:

```
Each parameter in the deserialization constructor on type 'CpatCognitiveServicesApp.Responses.TextToSpeechResponse' must bind to an object property or field on deserialization. Each parameter name must match with a property or field on the object. Fields are only considered when 'JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields' is enabled. The match can be case-insensitive.
```

This is what the JSON string looks like:

```
{
    "audioPreviewSuccess": true,
    "result": {
        "resultId": "ee80d3cf5f154fbba69401a4254b5b26",
        "reason": 9,
        "audioData": "UklGRnb1AABXQVZFZm10IBIAAAABAAEAgD4AAAB9AAACABAAAABkYXRhUPUAAAA",
        "properties": {}
    },
    "errorMessage": null
}
```

As you can see, my class should have the properties mapped out correctly. I believe it's having an issue because `properties` is coming back as `{}` in the JSON.

I've tried adding `UnknownTypeHandling = JsonUnknownTypeHandling.JsonNode` to the JsonSerializationOptions, but still got the same error. I've tried creating the following class to replace `SpeechSynthesisResult` in the hopes of skipping or bypassing `properties`, but the exception still occurs.

```
public class SpeechResult
{
    [JsonPropertyName("audioData")]
    public byte[] AudioData { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("reason")]
    public ResultReason Reason { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("resultId")]
    public string ResultId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("properties")]
    public JsonProperty Properties { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public SpeechResult(byte[] audioData, ResultReason reason, string resultId, JsonProperty properties)
    {
        AudioData  = audioData;
        Reason     = reason;
        ResultId   = resultId;
        Properties = properties;
    }

    public SpeechResult()
    {
        AudioData  = Array.Empty<byte>();
        Reason     = ResultReason.Canceled;
        ResultId   = string.Empty;
        Properties = new JsonProperty();
    }
}
```

I fear I'm missing something really silly, but I'm just not seeing it. My question is how can I successfully deserialize the string into the `TextToSpeechResponse` class?

Comment: Can you post your json strig as a text pls? Have some respect for another people. Also your image shows that you json is not valid

Comment: and I could not find SpeechSynthesisResult class

Comment: @Serge Added the actual JSON string. My apologies. I didn't do it before because the `AudioData` is very long. I reduced it for this purpose though. The `SpeechSynthesisResult` class is from `Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech`. It's what is returned from the API that I am using.

Comment: Is there a way to make it display _what field_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a bug in your JsonConstructor, fix a SpeechResult property, it should be the same as it is in a json string

```
public TextToSpeechResponse(bool audioPreviewSuccess, SpeechResult result, string? errorMessage, string message)
```